# British ETA for transfers?

Tags: uk, transit, eta, permits

A [quote from the *Independent*](https://www.caminodesantiago.me/community/threads/clarification-of-new-entry-rules-in-oct-24.84348/post-1205809):

> But when the ETA scheme takes full effect, all passengers except
> British and Irish nationals will need a permit – even if they are
> simply switching from one British Airways plane to another at Heathrow
> Terminal 5, or making a Star Alliance connection at Terminal 2.

Is it really that strict?  When does it take effect, and what will it take to get the permit?

Comment: This isn't a distinctive feature of the UK scheme, the US's ESTA scheme also applies to people who merely transit through the airport.

Comment: @JackAidley but that's because the US doesn't have international-to-international airside transfer. The UK does, so its weird that its required.

Comment: In more than one US airport, the walk from gate to customs was incredibly long, and it seemed there were opportunities along the way to sneak back to airside.  Unlikely one could avoid detection, I suppose.

Answer (score 10):

The UK ETA [currently applies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Travel_Authorisation_(United_Kingdom)) to Qatari passport holders; will apply to passports from Bahrain, Jordan, Kuwait, Oman, Saudi Arabia, and the UAE starting February 22, 2024; and is said to apply to other nationalities at as-yet-unannounced future dates.

Applications (for travelers of relevant nationalities) [can be made on the UK government's app or website](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/apply-for-an-electronic-travel-authorisation-eta), and [are indeed](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/qatar/transit/somewhere_else) required for people transiting without passing through border control.

Comment: So it is true.  Kind of silly, unless the goal is to make UK airports less busy.  I modified the question a bit.

Comment: @WGroleau As always with those *electronic travel*, it's for money

Comment: (+1) The UK scheme is similar to eg US, Canada and [New Zealand](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/preparing-a-visa-application/your-journey-to-new-zealand/before-you-travel-to-new-zealand/details-page/visa/nzeta). IMHO requiring an electronic travel authorisation for transit makes 100% sense from an immigration control perspective.

Comment: @Traveller the US doesn't have airside transit though. I can see why you would require it for countries that normally need a visa but requiring it for (say) German citizens seems like a complete overkill.

Comment: @JonathanReez Probably easier from an administrative point of view to require it for everyone than to set a list of exclusions that would need keeping up to date :-)